# Python socket server data sending error

Tags: python, string, sockets, send

so basically I have multiple conn.send(data) functions one after another in my server, problem is that when client receives that it puts it in one line, this is my server code:

```
server = "0.0.0.0"
port = 5851

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((server, port))
s.listen(10)

try:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print(addr)
    conn.send("chr Room_1")
    conn.send("cr Room_1")
    conn.send("cr Room_2")
    s.close()
    exit()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nexiting")
    s.close()
```

So when client receives this data it puts it in one line instead of 3 separate data variables.

Comment: That's because you never sent the newline character...

Comment: `send()` is not the same as `print()`; it sends _only_ what you tell it to. If you want to send multiple lines, you'll need to put `\n` (or whatever the client expects) between them yourself.

Comment: I added the \n but it still doens't work

Comment: And I also need them to be sent separately like different packets

Comment: On a TCP stream, you have absolutely no control over the packet boundaries that the other end receives.  To separate multiple chunks of data, you either have to separate them with some specific character, or precede each one with a length value so that the receiver knows how many bytes to read.